# Appium keep on asking "Failed to create session. You must include a platformName capability"

Tags: appium

I just try to start session the appium inspector yet it doesn't work as always. I have done all the stuff needed for running those app but still not working.
here's the sign:
"Failed to create session. You must include a platformName capability"

and here is my JSON representation:

```
"{
  "appium:appPackage": "com.emi.customer.app",
  "appium:appActivity": "com.emi.customer.app.MainActivity",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appium:deviceName": "Redmi Note 10S",
  "appium:udid": "GEW46XJ7O7V4YTFU"
}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You try with the desired caps once.

```
{
      "deviceName": "<YOUR_DEVICE_NAME>",
      "platformVersion": "<ANDROID_OS_VERSION>",
      "platformName": "Android",
      "appPackage": "<APP_PACKAGE>",
      "appActivity": "APP_ACTIVITY",
      "automationName": "UiAutomator2",}
```